# Changing EXTJS AJAX method from GET to POST will cause any performance problems

Tags: ajax, post, get, extjs3

I have an extjs request like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: someUrl,
    method: "GET",
    params: paramArray,         
    success: function(response){
        var responseText = response.responseText;
        //DO STUFF  
    },
    failure: function(response ) {
            // DO STUFF
            }
}); // end of ajax call
```

Now because the method is "GET", the number pf params in the url is limited. What is the best way around this? If i just change it to "POST", will it cause any side effects? (poor performance etc). The method should logically be a "GET" because it is not an update, just a fetch but to solve my ucrrent problem with parameters, I want to change to "POST".

Unless of curse there is a standard solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post)

POST has worse performance than GET